# Tkinter.canvas() лагает если добавить много элементов

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть холст с возможностью зума и перетаскивания, а так же в пятью сотнями элементов на нём. Пока на холсте не большое количество элементов всё в порядке, но когда я отдаляю камеру и на холсте становится уже много элементов то всё мягко говоря не в порядке. Зум и перетаскивание работают медленно и прерывисто, как будто игра в которой проседает фпс. Вот код зума и перетаскивания:

```
def scroll_start(event):
    c.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
def scroll_move(event):
    c.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)
def zoom(event):
    if event.delta > 0:
        c.scale('all', event.x-10, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
    if event.delta < 0:
        c.scale('all', event.x-10, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)

c.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", scroll_start)
c.bind("<B1-Motion>", scroll_move)
c.bind('<MouseWheel>', zoom)
```

Comment: tkinter не предназначен для интенсивного рисования, лучше взять pygame, например.

Comment: @insolor у меня интерфейс на tkinter я же не могу засунуть модуль от pygame в tkinter, или я чего то не знаю?

Comment: Не тестировал, но похоже что можно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16550818/4752653

Comment: @insolor это совсем другое, я имею в виду что весь интерфейс у меня в окне tkinter и соответственно я бы хотел что бы расположение элементов было в этом же окне, не открывать же отдельное окно для этого

Comment: В ответе, на который я дал ссылку, содержимое окна Pygame встраивается во фрейм tkinter.